# Does the multiplier for wielding a weapon two-handed apply to my Dex mod if I have the Weapon Finesse feat?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, combat, weapons, melee-combat

I have a rogue with the Weapon Finesse feat:

> When making a melee attack with a light weapon or rapier, you may use your DEX Mod instead of your strength Mod on the attack roll.

Since a rapier's hands datum is 1, I can wield it two-handed:

> If you wield it two-handed, add 1-1/2 times your STR Mod to melee damage instead.

If the character's Str mod is +1 and Dex mod is +3, and they have the Weapon Finesse feat, is a two-handed attack always +1.5, or can it be +4.5?

Comment: What if the weapon is keen and light?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, for three reasons:

First, Rapier specifically states:

> You can’t wield a rapier in two hands in order to apply 1½ times your Strength bonus to damage.

Second, Weapon Finesse allows you to use DEX mod instead of STR mod on **attack** rolls. Wielding a one handed weapon in two hands allows you to add to your **damage** rolls. Two completely different cases.

Third, you cannot use Weapon Finesse when wielding two handed weapons, or wielding a one handed weapon in two hands. There are a couple of specific items that change this ( iirc, Elven Courtblade from Races of the Wild and the <strike>cheesechain</strike> Spiked Chain ), but it is limited to those items.

Comment: Where does it specifically say that you cannot use Weapon Finesse when wielding two handed weapons?

Comment: @Macona `"with a light weapon or rapier"` Neither of these can be 2 handed.

Comment: @Macona - StuperUser has it right http://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/SRD:Light_Weapon : "Using two hands to wield a light weapon gives no advantage on damage; the Strength bonus applies as though the weapon were held in the wielder’s primary hand only."

Comment: Ok, but the Spiked Chain and the Aldori Dueling sword are not light weapons, so they can be finessed with two hands.

Comment: @Macona - Yes, but only because both weapons *specifically* state that they can be used as such. To do so, the spiked chain has to be one of your size, and you must have the Exotic Weapon Proficiency for the Aldori Dueling sword.

Comment: Dandwiki is NOT valid for Pathfinder - use http://www.d20pfsrd.com or it's irrelevant...