# Are Weapon Finesse and two-handed wielding mutually exclusive?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, weapons

I noticed some weapons, like the Elven Thinblade, can qualify for Weapon Finesse despite being classified as one-handed weapons. Does this mean I can wield it two-handed for 150% of my Dex bonus? Alternately, how can a Swashbuckler/Rogue multiclass apply Dex to attack rolls?

Comment: Related: [Does the multiplier for wielding a weapon two-handed apply to my Dex mod if I have the Weapon Finesse feat?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/15916/4089)

Comment: Addressing only a small part of the question's title: A list of the nonlight weapons usable with the feat Weapon Finesse—including several two-handed weapons—is in [this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/86566/8610).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108164/discussion-on-question-by-cobalt-are-weapon-finesse-and-two-handed-wielding-mutu).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### They are not mutually exclusive

And in fact there's even one weapon that's two-handed but finessable (the Spiked Chain). You can Power Attack with a finesse'd weapon as well, unless it's classified as a Light Weapon. Did the designers intend this? We'll never know, but the RAW is fairly clear on the matter.

There's no text in Weapon Finesse or the section on using a one-handed weapon in two hands that forbids it.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108163/discussion-on-answer-by-lord-gareth-are-weapon-finesse-and-two-handed-wielding-m).

Answer (score 0):

**Nothing in their respective descriptions states that they are mutually exclusive** (Though Light weapons state they can't be used two-handed, and Natural Weapons cannot be two-handed for obvious reasons)

If the weapon says it qualifies for Weapon Finesse, it means just that: You can use Weapon Finesse with that weapon. It does not imply anything else on its own.

Therefore: **No, you cannot use 1.5*DEX** to attack with a two-handed Finesse weapon (nor can you use 1.5*STR with any 2H weapon; it's for damage.)

**Swashbuckler/Rogue can use DEX for Attack by using a weapon that can be used with Weapon Finesse** (that Swashbucklers get at 1st level). Such weapons include: all light and natural weapons, Rapier, Spiked Chain, Whip, and others not in the PHB.